# Is there any support whatsoever for the ART Tube MP Project Series w/USB?

Tags: hardware, drivers, usb, sound, microphone

Here's the product's page off the mfg's website so you know exactly what i'm talking about.  Any help is appreciated.

http://artproaudio.com/products.asp?id=124&cat=9&type=86

Answer (score 2):

The Linux Audio Users mailing list would be a good place to ask.

http://lad.linuxaudio.org/subscribe/lau.html